# Alter table move taking long time

Tags: oracle, compression

I'm currently trying to compress a table in Oracle with the following statements:

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE COMPRESS FOR OLTP;
ALTER TABLE MOVE;
```

My question is: the `MOVE` operation is taking forever and unfortunately I forgot to state the `ONLINE` clause.

If I cancel it, will I lose data? Or is there any way to find out how long it will take?

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem in canceling the `MOVE` operation. Oracle just rolls back.

Progress information can often be gathered from [`[g]v$session_longops`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3022.htm), looking for sessions with `time_remaining > 0` (or the specific session you're interested in when you know that).